# solr find the most used word after a given word

Tags: solr

I need to find the most used word after a given word. For an example collection,

1. A B
2. A C
3. A B
4. B C

Here the most used word after word A is B.
How can I find this in solr?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a field with [ShingleFilterFactory](https://wiki.apache.org/solr/AnalyzersTokenizersTokenFilters#solr.ShingleFilterFactory) as one of its filters. This will generate a token sequence for each word when indexing the field, so that `A B C` is indexed as `A B` and `B C`. You will want to use the WhitespaceTokenizer or something similar for the field.

Make a request that searches for `field:A\ *` (meaning everything starting with the word `A`) as the query, and add a facet for the field.

```
facet=true&facet.field=field&facet.limit=10&facet.sort=count
```

will give you the ten most used sequences that start with the word `A`.

ShingleFilterFactory defaults to generating shingles with two tokens in each shingle, but you can tune this by altering `minShingleSize` and `maxShingleSize`.

Comment: Actually, just do a facet on that field, not a search. That will give you the count breakdowns, as the faceting works on the tokenized (so shingled) representation.

Comment: @AlexandreRafalovitch Well, as we want to limit the results to only words starting with A, we'll have to either use `q`, `fq` or `facet.prefix`, not sure which would shortcut the selection process first?

Comment: facet.prefix is what you want. The **q** is **fq** will limit the actual documents you are doing the counts against. If you are looking at all documents to derive your counts from, just leave **q** as _*:*_

Comment: @AlexandreRafalovitch Yes, but we *want* to limit the result to anything with A first, then an entry after. The actual count should be the same, reggardless of doing a prefix or a q/fq (the subset of documents are the same - the difference might be in cache utilization and when the subset of documents are wounded down. No need to do a count for documents when the prefix won't keep the counts anyway.